# With flink sql how to read kafka topic's key

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have table defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table /** mode('streaming')*/
(
        `pk` string,
        `id` string
)WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'key.format' = 'json',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092',
        'properties.group.id' = 'ef_entitlement_local_1',
        'topic-pattern' = 'entitlement_v1__.+?',
        'format' = 'json',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
        'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
        'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
        'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'
);
```

Here how do i read kafka topic's `key`. Seems like `key` is not part of `metadata`. I have tried using `key.format` and `key.fields`. These are not working.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't read the key.

Comment: Reading the key should also be a feature flink should support